# Duplicating text before a pattern to the same line?

Tags: sed

I have a file of code with multiple lines like:

```
catmouse.onClicked: {fileMCId.visible=false;allId
tacmouse.onClicked: {fileMCId.visible=false;allId
```

I would like to duplicate the text before "mouse" on each line, like this:

```
catmouse.onClicked:{fileMCId.visible=false;allId.cat
tacmouse.onClicked:{fileMCId.visible=false;allId.tac
```

I read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41822/duplicate-selected-words-with-sed-and-replace-it) solution but I didn't really get the logic

Comment: It would help if you explained what about "the logic" you didn't "get".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed 's/\(.*\)mouse.*/&.\1/' file
```

Output:

```
catmouse.onClicked: {fileMCId.visible=false;allId.cat
tacmouse.onClicked: {fileMCId.visible=false;allId.tac
```